# A GUI program to identify file types and fix extensions accordingly

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-management, gui, file-format

Is there a GUI program that will allow me to determine the true file type of a given set of files and then change their extensions accordingly?

The program must:

- Be a GUI
- Be able to identify a file's true file type (through its header or using a similar smart method, instead of simply relying on its extension)
- Be able to change the file's extension
- Be able to perform the above on multiple files or an entire folder

At the moment the only program out there that I'm aware of that does something similar is [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html), which is a command-line program. It has a GUI version, but this is limited by comparison and doesn't seem to allow working with more than one file at a time.